# compile lanshark on mac

Tags: macos, open-source, compilation

I am trying to compile [lanshark](http://lanshark.29a.ch/en/Downloads.html) for mac, but do not know how to compile on mac. I am guessing that it is possible to compile linux source code on mac. if not how can i get this program to run?

Answer (score 1):

A mac is, under the hood, a BSD 'darwin' box.

Go and take a look at the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) webpage. You'll find lots of interesting information (like where to get a compiler etc ) there.

Another place to go for an apple development environment is [apple (xcode)](http://www.apple.com/macosx/developers/#xcode) ...

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to get that to run, but it will be a bit of work.  The source may need a small amount of modification, depending on exactly how the protocol works (if they're using raw ethernet, that is done quite differently).  Also, the OS X linker (ld) works completely differently to the Linux linker, and so the build system will need a bit of tinkering.

However, the compilers and build utilities are in the XCode bundle on your install disk, or at the download link in the other answer, so install that and give it a go.  If you're lucky, just following the Linux instructions will build it.